# Objective-c returning null

Tags: objective-c

I have created a class to store a number. The number is passed in via a method which takes an int, and then holds it in an NSNumber * object. See below:

```
- (IBAction)memoryPlus:(UIButton *)sender {
    int result = [self.display.text intValue];
    [self.memory memoryPlus:result];
}
```

result always gets the correct value, however memoryPlus:result is returning null. When I put a breakpoint on the method call, the debugger does not enter the method, instead moves to the end of the method.

The Memory .m file below should be taking the value of result and assigning it to calculatorMemoryString but this is not happening.

```
@interface CalculatorMemory()
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *calculatorMemoryString;
@end

@implementation CalculatorMemory

@synthesize calculatorMemoryString;

-(void)memoryPlus:(int)memoryValue{
    calculatorMemoryString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",memoryValue];
}

-(NSString *)memoryRecall{
    return calculatorMemoryString;
}

-(void)memoryClear{
    NSLog(@"CalculatorMemory: memoryClear called");
}

@end
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Show the code where you instantiate the class `self.memory`

Comment: Learn how to debug -- please!!  When you find a bad value, trace it back to its source.

Answer (score 2):

This means that `self.memory` is nil. The number one cause of "nothing is happening" is that the thing you're messaging is nil.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, however I have set it up the same way as the other classes so I don't understand how it could be nil. This is my view controller:

Comment: I have set it up the same way as the other classes so I don't understand. This is my view controller: #import     "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"
#import "CalculatorMemory.h"
.@interface CalculatorViewController()
.@property (nonatomic,strong) CalculatorMemory  *memory;
.@property (nonatomic,strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
.@end
.@implementation CalculatorViewController
.@synthesize display = _display;
.@synthesize brain=_brain;
.@synthesize memory=_memory;

Comment: When you log out the value of `self.memory` here (or check it in the debugger), is it nil or not? Nothing you've put in the above comment initializes `self.memory`.